# How to find first element that's less than the x in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this question in which I wanted to loop through an array starting from large number to smaller number and compare the number in the array against the x provided.

My code was supposed to be like this:

```
function convertToRoman(num) {

  var decimalNum = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];

  while (num > 0){ // to prevent the number from reaching zero
    for (var k = 0; k < decimalNum.length; k++) { //to loop through the array

    if(num > decimalNum[k]) {return k}; //this is the part in which I wanted to return the element that is next in the array that is less than the num
    }
  }


}

convertToRoman(36);
```

For example, if the num = 36, then the next number in the array that is less than 36 would be 10. So I wanted to return 10. How do I do that?

I tried to find solutions online but the only solutions I found was for Java or C++ which is completely different from JavaScript, correct? And I don't think that binary search should be used as well...

Comment: `return arr.find(el => el < num)`?

Comment: You can always search for the index of 36 with binary search and then pick the next smallest.

Comment: use the embedded js engine for your code and why do you use a `while` instead of an `if`? (you can even use the if as a short circuit proof in your function)

Comment: Should `return k` not be `return decimalNum[k]`?

Comment: Use `return decimalNum[k]` and break the for loop and why are you using while loop just to check 1 value. Use if condition instead.

Comment: `arr.find` is not supported by ie.

Comment: what would you like to get if you have a value of `40`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Return the value not the index you are on:**

```js
function convertToRoman(pNumber) {

      var array = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
     
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (pNumber > array[i]) {//if the current item is smaller than the parameter
                return array[i]; //return the value at the index you are on
            }; 
         } 
    }
    
    console.log(convertToRoman(36));//returns 10
```

When you get to a item that is smaller, then return that item

Answer (score 0):

for that you should get the value not index

```js
function convertToRoman(num) {

  var decimalNum = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];

   //   while (num > 0) { // to prevent the number from reaching zero
    for (var k = 0; k < decimalNum.length; k++) { //to loop through the array

      if (num > decimalNum[k]) {
        return decimalNum[k]
      }; //this is the part in which I wanted to return the element that is next in the array that is less than the num
     }
//  }
}

console.log(convertToRoman(36));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will work in IE and regardless of how the values in the array are sorted

```
var lesser = decimalNum.filter(function(dec) {
  return dec < num;
});
var result = Math.max.apply(null, lesser);
```

If you know that the `decimalNum` array is alwys sorted the way it is in your code, you can simply replace the `Math.max` part with `lesser[0]`